# How to get off a minecart unharmed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, when I exit a minecart, I often lose half a heart (sometimes even more). But occasionally I don't get harmed. I wasn't able to find a rule, what to do to exit the cart unharmed ... is there a specific point to look at? Or something to do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If there is only one block of headroom above the cart, the player will take half a heart of damage as he bangs his head on the ceiling.

Comment: Technically it's not banging your head, it's *suffocating*!

Comment: the difference is that head banging involves a lot more heavy metal

Comment: So it's head banging if the ceiling is iron or gold blocks.

Comment: @Alex: It doesn't always involve heavy metal. It depends on the material of the ceiling. Sometimes, normal rock can be enough to bang your head on.

Comment: @Joetjah I was actually making a joke about [this kind of headbanging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headbanging) :)

Comment: @Alex: And with 'rock' I was referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_music ;)

Comment: @Joetjah oh dear, I don't know why I didn't see that hehe :) I haven't had any coffee today, that's my excuse! \m/

Comment: @Alex: you just banged your head too hard to see clear... Oh man, this level of humor is going down more and more

Comment: @Joetjah You joke about banging too hard, but I was going to see a concert once that was cancelled because the guitarist hurt his neck/back by headbanging too much!